# Grafana - cast elastic string value to

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I would like to graph values from elasticsearch with grafana.
The problem is that the value is stored as string:

```
[
  {"timestamp": 123123123123,
   "value": "12"},
  {"timestamp": 123123123123,
   "value": "14"}
]
```

When I then select metric in grafana 'Max', there is no value shown.

I tried in the `metric`->`options` to set
script to `parseInt(_value)` which does not help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible on the Grafana or [Elasticsearch level](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/convert-string-to-numeric/97449). Fix your ES field mapping (`double` datatype for `value` field) https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html and you will receive correct format for Grafana directly from ES.